# Is ASUS P5K-V Comptatable with this Crucial M4 SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard

Upgrading my old pc which has an Asus P5K V Motherboard, and im looking to add an SSD to it.

I've come across Crucials website which says these 2 products are available

http://www.crucial.com/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=49C6AB1FA5CA7304

which is this http://www.ebuyer.com/product/266526 hard drive I believe.

Could somebody confirm that these should be compatable?

Many thanks

Comment: @Peter Maxwell is right. Your going to also want to switch your drive to `ACHI` mode in the bios of the motherboard

Comment: I believe you mean *AHCI, but yes @BrandonKreisel is correct. Unless it's already in that mode.

Comment: @PeterMaxwell yep, please ignore the typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a SATA port it should work just like any other HDD, just way faster.